# Dealing with duplicates using <set> in C++ when I want to read from a text file?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find a fast way to read all the words in a text file and save only the unique ones and the number of times they appear.

How will set work for this? If I save words into it, will it automatically discard duplicate words, or will it simply give an error message?

The only alternative solution I can think of is to save each one into a vector, use the unique algorithm and then save into map, but this seems to be inefficient.

Comment: Did you consider to consult the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) before asking here?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see where it says how duplicates are dealt with

Comment: @OkIsayHi see documentation of the `insert` member function of `set`, it specifies what happens when the element is already in the set.

Comment: Since you actually *don't* want to store a set of unique values, using a `std::set` makes no sense. (If you think you do and the values are the words, then you're forgetting that what you actually want to store is the number of times each word appears.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you need is a `map<string,int>` not a set. So each word has its own counter

This allows you to have

```
"car" -> 1
"house" -> 55
"cat" -> 42
```

so you do

```
map<string,int> wordCounts;
....
// assume you have list of words in array called words

for(int i =0; i < wordCount; i++)
{
    string word = words[i];
    wordCounts[word] = wordCount[word] + 1;
}
```

This is slightly long winded but clearer what is going on. If wordCounts doesnt include an entry for say 'cat' already it will create one and set the count to 0 for you. Next time you have 'cat' it will retrive the current counter and add one

Comment: fleshing this out a bit... after `map<string, int> words;`, you just need to execute `++words[word];` where `word` is a string containing a word you read from the file. Could write the whole program in about 5 lines.

Comment: @M.M ty for compensating for my laziness

Comment: What do you mean by "its own counter?"

Comment: @OkIsayHi the `map` maps a string to an integer; that integer counts how many times the string has been found.

Comment: @M.M I've misunderstood set, but I want map with the restriction that all values are unique. What do you propose is the best way to do this?

Comment: @OkIsayHi maps are like sets in that they only allow one instance of a key. The solution they are providing allows the container to also store your appearance count for each word.

Comment: @OkIsayHi You said in the question that you also wanted to count how many instances there were of each unique word. That's what the map is for .  If you actually do not need this requirement then you can use `set` which will store one copy of each unique word, and no counter.

Comment: Ah yes thank you! I forgot about the uniqueness property of maps. Quick question though, what is the wordCount[word] supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

According to this:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert

It will return both an iterator that points to the newly inserted node OR an iterator that points to the existing node and a Boolean value set to true if the insertion is successful. So simply insert every word, and look for true or false in the second element in the returned pair to see if it was new or old.

Comment: So I can insert without accidentally inserting duplicates?

Comment: Sets don't allow duplicates. If the key is already present in the map, it will inform you by way of the return value. It will not affect the value that is already present in the set.

Comment: I see. That is very convenient!

Answer (score -1):

you can use set but instead of saving string you can save struct.
this struct will look like that :

```
struct countedString{
int times;
std::string value;
countedString(const std::string& _value, int number)
:times(number),
value(_value)
{}
}
```

and whenever you add an item to the set you will first find it , if exsits than you will create new object using times+1 otherwise you will just create it with.
find a value in a set is pretty efficent beacuse its just like map but every value is also the key.
but you will have to define a how to compare your struct, it will look like that:

```
struct classcomp { bool operator() (const countedString& lhs,
const countedString& rhs) const
{return lhs.value < rhs.value;} 
};
```

and finally you will need to init the set like that :

```
std::set<countedString,classcomp> words_set
```

Comment: This is a poor idea compared to a `std::map<std::string, unsigned int>`, since for the set you would need to erase then insert at every update.  Also, your `operator()` is incorrect - it should `return lhs.value < rhs.value;` or similar.